# How to disable the SAP field auto-complete/enhanced search?

Tags: sap

I am running a new SAP system release and it has a new auto-complete feature for some fields, such as this:

[image]

It is a cool feature, but sometimes you already know the input and you want to quickly <kbd>tab</kbd> through the fields. With the auto-complete feature, I am not able to do this any more.

Is it possible to disable it?

Comment: Which version of SAP GUI are you using?

Comment: SAP_UI 740 SAPK-74008INSAPUI

Comment: Ok, I found a system with `SAP_UI 740 0006 SAPK-74006INSAPUI User Interface Technology 7.40` which I have access to. As I am no expert in ERP modules, could you please post also the transaction name that you took your screenshot from, so I can research more?

Comment: That is great @Jagger! This was from transaction WB21. But I believe this option is available on several other transactions.

Comment: With this `SAP_UI` component version I do not have the autocomplete by default, so I assume it depends on the SAP Logon Client. Could you also post your SAP Logon Client version? You can find it  like on this screenshot [here](http://i60.tinypic.com/2lxt5jo.png). It might be also dependent on the Theme you are using. You can check it exactly as shown [here](http://i58.tinypic.com/28wo06.png).

Comment: Hi, you can find my SAP logon info here: http://i58.tinypic.com/28wo06.jpg . I am using the Corbu theme, but I don't think it's related.

Comment: Hi, you pasted my screenshot instead of yours, could you correct the link?

Comment: Sorry! http://i.imgur.com/xzFf75M.png

Answer (score 6):

In your SAP Logon, select your options:

[image]

Then go to Interaction Design > Visualization 2 and click on Do Not Show Enhanced search.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Go to: customized local lay-out 
OPTIONS  /  Local Data  /  History  /  History Status: OFF
Don’t forget you will have to APPLY  /  OK and then fully log out and then log back in.